Why talk back functionality in French has a great delay?
I am trying to check the Talkback functionality in French (as the app supports both En and Fr).
Once I move focus back and forth in English it Talkback pretty fast, however, once I check device settings in French  (app also uses fr locale), the Talkback reads buttons with great delay - like 10 seconds. To put it differently, once a user moves a focus from one button to another TalkBack will read the button in 10 sec delay.
Let me know what am I missing here?

Talkback, so using Text-to-Speech, which is using web to produce audio, maybe "french serwers" are somehow overloaded or having connectivity problems... worth checking another device
